# Why do “specific” component renders a more “generic” one?

Tags: reactjs

This is straight from [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) site.

```
function Dialog(props) {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      <h1 className="Dialog-title">
        {props.title}
      </h1>
      <p className="Dialog-message">
        {props.message}
      </p>
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}

function WelcomeDialog() {
  return (
    <Dialog
      title="Welcome"
      message="Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!" />
  );
}
```

from Reactjs docs "In React, this is also achieved by composition, where a more “specific” component renders a more “generic” one and configures it with props:"

I find the statement bit confusing. Generally shouldn't more generic items create specific ones?

Comment: if you can explain your doubts, relating to the code you posted, it will be more feasible for me to understand what you meant.

Comment: @snmJpa: in the sentence `where a more “specific” component renders a more “generic” one`, you should read "renders" as "makes use of". The generic component *is* being used to create specific ones. It's just that the way to use a component is to render it.

Comment: make use of and also pass the data that the generic component is waiting for (btw not 100% of the time).

Comment: @NicholasTower, so a specific component renders a generic component, but is the generic component that helps to create a specific component?

Comment: A generic component can render anything, but requires configuration to do so. A specific component knows the configuration, and so it uses the generic component, passing in that configuration.